# CSS nowrap for other than text elements?

Tags: css, html, nowrap

Is there a way to avoid wrapping of a `div`'s
content when the content is not just text e.g. several buttons?

Comment: do you mean `overflow: hidden`? Please let as know what "wrapping" means

Comment: "wrapping" means that white-space:nowrap; doesn't work for non-text, content gets wrapped (takes more than 1 line)

Comment: Please show a case where `white-space: nowrap` does not work for buttons. `Button` elements are text content, in HTML and CSS terms.

Comment: If it doesn't work try to add ```display: inline-block``` to the elements that still wrap. It should follow the ```white-space: nowrap``` rule. I'm instead facing the problem of having it also to not overflow but resize the parent element.

Answer (score 44):

`white-space:nowrap;` should do the trick.

```css
#foo {
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <input type="button" value="hello"/>
  <input type="button" value="hello"/>
  <input type="button" value="hello"/>
  <input type="button" value="hello"/>
  <input type="button" value="hello"/>
  <input type="button" value="hello"/>
  <input type="button" value="hello"/>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ozanuc/1/edit)

Comment: Demo doesn't work in my browser (Chrome 60.0.3112.113). I had to add "overflow:hidden" to "#foo".

Answer (score 0):

You can set both these properties in CSS:

`white-space:nowrap;` and `max-width:something;`

Answer (score -3):

You can declare static positions for the other contents using

```
position:absolute;
```